# Samsung phone stuck in Download mode with "vbmeta partition read failed" error

Tags: samsung, boot-loop

The Samsung phone is not starting up. It shows the error message in the picture.

> <!>
>
> Partition boot
> Reason avb_slot_verity.c:143: ERROR: [...]
> [...] Error loading data from partition.
> [check_secure_boot] vbmeta partition read failed
> [check_secure_boot] partition read failed

<sup>[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CFWr.jpg)</sup>

I tried flashing it with Odin, it works for a moment then switches off and comes back on with the error message.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Could you please include the error message as  text into your question? The quality of the image is so bad that I can not really read what is written on your screen. Also text inside images is bad for search engines so other people having the same error will not be able to find your question potential answers.

Comment: Try a factory reset

Comment: you *tried* flashing it with Odin, or you flashed successfully with Odin? what works only for moment but fails, flashing or booting?

Comment: I flashed successfully with Odin then the phone works for a moment and switches off, fails to boot and shows that same exact error message. I flashed with Odin 3 times same results. At this point I'am guessing it has something thing to do with the hardware being faulty.